# How to calculate number of unique names in an excel row?

Tags: mysql, r, excel, analysis

Suppose I have a data set of n rows:

```
happy   sad happy           hello   sad happy  
random      check   check   random          random
...
```

I need to count the unique values in the row, the blank cells should not be counted.
In the above example the first row should give `3` as an answer,
the second row should give me `2`.

The data is in rows and I cannot transpose.
Please provide suggestions in `excel/sql/r`.

Comment: If you know how to get the data into R (say a data.frame), it's a matter of ˙apply(x, MARGIN = 1, function(m) length(unique(m)))`, that is assuming the number  of names in a row is constant. If not, some other structure like a list may be more handy. This changes little - instead of `apply` you would use `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

If A1:G1 is your data row, then this is one way:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A1:G1)>0,MATCH(A1:G1,A1:G1,0),""), IF(LEN(A1:G1)>0,MATCH(A1:G1,A1:G1,0),""))>0,1))
```

What I'm doing here is discounting any cell that appears more than once, using an `IF`. Such cells are assigned a value of 0. The ones that don't repeat are assigned the value 1. Then I sum those. The `LEN` causes the formula to skip over blank cells.

Note that this is an *array* formula: you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Return when you've entered it into a cell.

Comment: But do unpick the formula so you know *how* it works. It's one of those formulas that you commit to memory after many years!